# Replace text inside of square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var a = "[i] earned [c] coin for [b] bonus";
```

How to get string "__ earned __ coin for __ bonus" from the variable above in JavaScript?

All I want to do is to replace all the bracket `[]` and its content to `__`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
a = a.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, '__');
```

if you expect newlines to be possible, you can use:

```
a = a.replace(/\[[^\]]*?\]/g, '__');
```

Comment: In your second example, you don't need to make the `*` ungreedy.

Comment: thanks, btw can you explain me how does it work? perhaps there is a complete tutorial about this?

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info is helpful ... will try to explain later if have a chance

Comment: @alex: Yeah, I just like using it always for safety in case the expression changes...

Comment: Some characters like `[` and `]` have special meaning in regular expressions, so when you actually want a bracket you have to escape it with \. So the first item (`\[`) matches the opening bracket. Then comes `[^\]]`. The `[` and final `]` indicate a character class allowing a group of characters to be placed inside. In this case we only need one character (`]` though we need to escape it here as `\]` since otherwise the regular expression parser might think we ended the class), but we use the character class with the caret (^) to mean "not" (not a bracket).

Comment: The `*?` (which as Afrig pointed out, can be simplified in this case to `*` but I chose not to because it is often dangerous to use it since it can replace more than you intended) means that the previous character or class can be present 0 or more times. So, `[^\]]*?` means find anything which is not an ending bracket any number of times. We use this instead of just `.*?` since `.` will not match newlines. Finally the `\]` at the end finds the last bracket.

Comment: Above solution is not working in nodejs

Comment: It's working at https://www.mycompiler.io/view/9wHorMZA6D0 . Try pasting your code there?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a fun example of matching groups.

```js
var text = "[i] italic [u] underline [b] bold";

document.body.innerHTML = text.replace(/\[([^\]]+)\]/g, '(<$1>$1</$1>)');
```

---

### Breakdown

```js
/           // BEGIN  pattern
  \[        // FIND   left bracket (literal) '['
    (       // BEGIN  capture group 1
      [     // BEGIN  character class
        ^   // MATCH  start anchor OR
        \]  // MATCH  right bracket (literal) ']'
      ]     // END    character class
      +     // REPEAT 1 or more
    )       // END    capture group 1
  \]        // MATCH  right bracket (literal) ']'
/           // END    pattern
g           // FLAG   global search
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = a.replace(/\[[^\]]+\]/g, '__');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/JaHAW/).